# Complex regex request - need three variables from string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to explode string data like the following three examples:

- 02/07/2019 - RACE 2 SHANE MURPHY PAINTING 366M
- 28/07/2019 - RACE 2 WYNNUM HAULAGE Maiden F 366M
- 01/12/2011 - RACE 1 MCGUIGAN WINES POKOLBIN MAIDEN 400M

And populate table information with subsets.

Because the strings all start the same I have managed to extract race date [0] and the race number [3].

I have looked at regex but I'm not sure how to extract the name of the race and race length.

Using the above examples the race names extracted should be:

- SHANE MURPHY PAINTING
- WYNNUM HAULAGE Maiden F
- MCGUIGAN WINES POKOLBIN MAIDEN

And the race distances extracted should be:

- 366M
- 366M
- 400M

Is there a simple way to generate this data from the strings using PHP? Do I need to use both regex and explode? Any suggestions please?

I am able to extract the date and race number since these are at the top of the string, but I cannot extract the other variables due to the spaces after Race X, etc.

```
$race_info = explode(" ",$row['race_name']);

echo "Race number: {$race_info[3]} <br>";
echo "Race date: {$race_info[0]} <br>";
// need to find race name (in middle of the string)
echo "Race name: ";
// need to find last word ending in M (e.g. 600M, 1200M, 40M)
echo "Race length: ";
```

Comment: `^([\d]{2}\/[\d]{2}\/[\d]{4}) - RACE ([0-9]+) (.*?) ([\d]+M)$` may be a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preg_match function would work well for this assuming the race info is as consistent as you show here. Here is an example code snippet:

```
$str = '02/07/2019 - RACE 2 SHANE MURPHY PAINTING 366M';

if ( preg_match( '/^([0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}) - RACE ([0-9]{1,}) (.*) ([0-9]{3,}M)$/', $str, $matches ) ) {
        echo "Race number: ${matches[2]}\n";
        echo "Race date: ${matches[1]}\n";
        echo "Race name: ${matches[3]}\n";
        echo "Race length ${matches[4]}\n";
} else {
        echo "Cannot parse the string\n";
}
```

This would produce the following output:

```
Race number: 2
Race date: 02/07/2019
Race name: SHANE MURPHY PAINTING
Race length 366M
```

Note that it's the matches in parenthesis "()" that ultimately end up in the $matches array passed to the preg_match function. As usual, lots more info available online: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Thanks for this option. Yes the string is pretty consistent, except I've been told the distance might sometimes 5 characters, e.g. 1050M. I can now see how the array is created using ().

Answer (score 1):

There are two main approaches, the first is to use a regex...

Using `([\d\/]{10,}) - RACE (\d*) ([\w ]*) (\d*M)` will match:

- `([\d\/]{10,})` a combination of 10 numbers and / - which is the
  date.
- `- RACE (\d*)` which is the literal RACE followed by a    numerical
  race number.
- `([\w ]*)` which is a sequence of letters(and spaces) for the name
- `(\d*M)` a numeric followed by the literal M.

So the code is...

```
$row = ['race_name' => '28/07/2019 - RACE 2 WYNNUM HAULAGE Maiden F 366M'];

preg_match("/([\d\/]{10,}) - RACE (\d*) ([\w ]*) (\d*M)/", 
    $row['race_name'],
    $race_info);
echo "Race number: {$race_info[2]} <br>";
echo "Race date: {$race_info[1]} <br>";
echo "Race name: {$race_info[3]}<br>";
// need to find last word ending in M (e.g. 600M, 1200M, 40M)
echo "Race length: {$race_info[4]} <br>";
```

OR, you could just stick to using explode and work out which parts are which.  You already have the date and the race number, the last one will be the distance and all of the bit between the race number and the distance is joined back together to give the race name...

```
$row = ['race_name' => '28/07/2019 - RACE 2 WYNNUM HAULAGE Maiden F 366M'];
$race_info = explode(" ",$row['race_name']);
echo "Race number: {$race_info[3]} <br>";
echo "Race date: {$race_info[0]} <br>";
$length = count($race_info);
// need to find race name (in middle of the string)
$name = implode(" ", array_slice($race_info, 4, $length-5));
echo "Race name: {$name}<br>";
// need to find last word ending in M (e.g. 600M, 1200M, 40M)
echo "Race length: {$race_info[$length - 1]} <br>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution here Nigel. I'm getting my head around preg_match and I can see how this now works. I like how you solved the 4-5 char race length with a numeric match.